# Open workbook with dynamic name

Tags: excel, vba

I have to download one workbook every day.

The name of the workbook always starts with `CMVOLT`.

Whole file name is `CMVOLT_22112019`.

`22112019` represents date and changes daily.

I open this workbook as follows:

```
Sub openwb()

Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook

sPath = "C:\Users\Windows\Downloads\"
sFile = sPath & "CMVOLT_22112019.CSV"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

End Sub
```

So I need to change workbook name daily.

Is there a way to select sheet starting with `CMVOLT` with VBA?

I will have only one sheet at a time starting with `CMVOLT`.

Comment: @braX How can I activate window starting from name `CMVOLT` ?

Comment: @braX I have tried`Windows("CMVOLT_22112019.CSV").Activate`

Comment: Here,date will keep changing, so how do I activate that windows?

Comment: According to this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.activate(method) - `Workbooks("CMVOLT_22112019.CSV").Activate` should work.

Comment: But assuming that works, so should `wb.Activate`

Comment: I tried, but it did't work, reason behind this is, today name of worksheet could be `CMVOLT_22112019.CSV` but tomorrow it will be `CMVOLT_23112019.CSV`

Comment: But that gets set when you open it - or are you later calling some other routine and no longer have access to the `wb` object? If so, define it globally instead of in the routine so you can reference it in another routine. At any rate, your question now is no longer in the scope of your original question, and you are not including all of the relevant code, so it's impossible to really help you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure there will be at least one and only one CSV file using that naming convention in the folder, you can use this

```
Sub openwb()

  Dim sPath As String, sFile As String, sWild As String
  Dim wb As Workbook

  sPath = "C:\Users\Windows\Downloads\"
  sWild = sPath & "CMVOLT_*.CSV"
  sFile = sPath & Dir(sWild)

  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim sDate as String
    sDate = Format(now, "ddmmyyyy")
    sFile = sPath & "CMVOLT_" & sDate & ".CSV"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the system-date with the date-function into a string variable and manipulate after it this variable a way, you get it into the format of your date in the filename.
Then you use the variable the way like the path and open your file.